# How can i access dropdown list elements which is inside the DOM using jquery?

Tags: jquery

This is the code. I am trying to access the dropdown list elements of the DOM.

```
boot.html

<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse"    data-target=".navbar-collapse">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="">dummy name</a>
        </div>
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse" style="height: 5px;">
           <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="active"><a href="./index1.html">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">About us</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Solutions</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Customers</a></li>

                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Switch      Theme<b class="caret"></b></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li> <a href="boot.html" tabindex="-1">Dark</a>     </li>
                        <li>  <a href="boot.html" tabindex="-1">Apple</a>       </li>
                        <li>  <a href="boot.html" tabindex="-1" >Blue</a>     </li>
                <li>  <a href="boot.html" tabindex="-1">Pearl</a>     </li>
               <li>  <a href="boot.html" tabindex="-1">Box</a>     </li>
               <li>  <a href="boot.html" tabindex="-1">Pane</a>     </li>
               <li>  <a href="boot.html" tabindex="-1">glue</a>     </li>
               <li>  <a href="boot.html" tabindex="-1">Gun</a>     </li>
               <li>  <a href="boot.html" tabindex="-1">Interim</a>     </li>
               <li>  <a href="boot.html" tabindex="-1">Squash</a>     </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>

        </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
      </div>
    </div>
```

and  tag to access css file:

```
 <link class="me" href="css/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

This is the jquery code that i used. I am trying to alter the  tag to point to different css file but it doesnt change the link tag to point my desired css file:

```
<script>
var link = $('link.me');

(function(){ $('ul.dropdown-menu').children('li').click(function(){link.attr('href','cssh/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.min.css')});}
)();
</script>
```

Comment: Have you tried implementing this inside a document ready handler..?

Comment: `class = "me"`. Correct this

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy yes. actually this format $(function($(myjquerycode)))();  will take care of it

Comment: @ShaunakD: Ya corrected. and i included as mentioned by sridhar but still it doesnt work

Comment: I know it, but `var link = $('link.me');` is outside of the ready handler..

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy: hmm ya thats a dumb mistake of me. Anyway thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error in class attribution

Try with

```
<link class="me" href="css/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Script

```
    $(window).load(function () {
    var link = $('link.me');
    $('ul.dropdown-menu li').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        link.attr('href', 'css/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.min.css') //check css/ or cssh/
    });
   });
```

Comment: @Dinesh Ravi Sorry for the disturbance, In href cssh or css please make sure

Comment: @sridhar R:Sorry and thanks alot. It works. It seems i misplaced my script.

Answer (score 1):

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/xMaLP/1/)**

Correct your snippet to this,

1. `class="me"` in `<link>` tag.
2. **[`event.preventDefault()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/)** for `<a>` clicks to prevent default action.
3. Also you can use this selector `$('ul.dropdown-menu li').click(..)`

---

HTML :

```
<link class="me" href="css/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

JS :

```
(function () {
    var link = $('link.me');

    $('ul.dropdown-menu li').click(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        link.attr('href', 'cssh/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.min.css')
    });
})();
```